# BuildConfig boolean variable always set to false

Tags: android, gradle

I have 3 environments : debug, staging and release.
I'm trying to add a simple Staging flag (similar to the default Debug flag) so I could programatically know what server url to use at runtime.

For some reason, the generated BuildConfig always seems to have the STAGING variable as **False**.
(Despite the fact that in build variants in the IDE I specifically choose "staging" option before compiling and running.)

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            manifestPlaceholders = [enableCrashReporting:"true"]
            signingConfig signingConfigs.my_debug
            buildConfigField "boolean", "STAGING", "false"
        }
        staging {
            initWith debug
            buildConfigField "boolean", "STAGING", "true"
        }
        release {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "STAGING", "false"
            ...
        }
}
```

Comment: This exact configuration works fine for me.

Comment: I have some module that I use in my project though, I think maybe that's the reason perhaps.
When i compile, it's like it's always compiling "debug" instead of "staging" build type

Comment: That may be the case. Have you tried to run the gradle task `assembleStaging`??

Comment: I tried running "compileStagingSources" and it seemed to work only when I added debug and staging buildtypes in gradle to the module that the app is using.
I cannot find assembleStaging however

Comment: `compileStagingSources` should do the job. After you do that, in the generated `BuildConfig` file do you get the correct value?

Comment: yes. After I do `compileStagingSources`, the value is correct.
But then when I try to run the project again, it builds it as a debug variant, and thus the variable becomes 'false' again

Comment: Well, then you will have to investigate that issue. Check your build output window to see what task is being executed. This will be at the very top. Something like this `Executing tasks: [:app:assembleStaging] in project ...`. If the task is "assembleDebug" then you may want to post another question/update this one for this particular issue. I am not sure why that would be happening.

Comment: that's the strange thing indeed - when I assemble the project, it executes the `compileDebugSources` instead of the Staging version, even though the build variant is chosen as `staging`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223240/discussion-between-siddharth-sharma-and-bvtp).